# Inserting cell by cell into a Dataframe of unknown size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below works fine. What I like to do is instead of printing **"d"** I would like to insert values into a dataframe. The driver is pulling data out of a table the table size may vary so I find the rxc. How can I insert these values into a DataFrame as it loops through a table.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

# to identify the table rows
r = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div")
# to identify table columns
c = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")
# to get row count with len method
rc = len (r)
# to get column count with len method
cc = len (c)
# to traverse through the table rows excluding headers
for i in range (2, rc+2 + 2):
# to traverse through the table column 
    for j in range (1, cc + 1):
# to get all the cell data with text method
        d = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td["+str(j)+"]").text
        print(d) #add to dataframe here
```

Comment: Why don't you use the standard `read_html` method for reading tables?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. I am reading the table with code posted here I am trying to out data in a dataframe.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the possible solution.

The values are appended to this list in the inner loop. When the inner loop for a row completes, the row_data list is appended to the DataFrame as a new row using the `append()` method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
    r = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div")
    c = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td")
    rc = len(r)
    cc = len(c)
    for i in range(2, rc+2 + 2):
        row_data = []  # Create a list to store the values of each row
        for j in range(1, cc + 1):
            d = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='contentScrollPoint']/div[4]/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td["+str(j)+"]").text
            row_data.append(d) 
        
        df = df.append(pd.Series(row_data), ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```